# Linq query not fetching record

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to fetch a record from SQL table, I can fetch the data when I do in SQL query, but not in LINQ.

My sql query is:

```
select sum(datediff(Day,2018-04-31,2018-04-30)) as dd 
  from lms03192018.dbo.LeaveRequestModels 
 where leaveTypeId = '1'  
       and requestUserId = '5dc64ba7-8cf8-45dd-80f2-a8700e7dad2e' 
       and FromDate = '2018-04-30'
```

It gives me result: 1.

I want the same result from LINQ, but instead of hard code dates I have to use a variable and a view model date value. Below is my attempted code:

```
var month = new DateTime (userInputDate.Year, userInputDate.Month , 1);
                          var last = month.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
                          var nextmonth = month.AddMonths(1);

var diffMonthLeavesCount = leaveApprovedList
                              .Where(x => x.leaveTypeId == leaveTypeId 
                                          && x.requestUserId == person.Id 
                                          && x.FromDate.Month == userInputDate.Month 
                                          && x.ToDate.Month == nextmonth.Month)
                              .Select(x => SqlMethods.DateDiffDay(last,x.FromDate))
                              .Sum();
```

Comment: in LInq you're containing with both `FromDate` and `ToDate` but in SQL query only `FromDate`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I checked it with the same Where clauses as in SQL query and i fetches the record. i want result of DateDiffDay The  issue is in SqlMethods.DateDIffDay. At run Time the value of last is 
 Date: {4/30/2018 12:00:00 AM} . and the value of FromDate is : 2018-04-30 00:00:00.000 in my table. What issue can DateDiffDay have in these two values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your c# code you using the Month comparison, I ignore it:

```
leaveApprovedList.Where(l => l.leaveTypeId = "1" &&
                             l.requestUserId == "5dc64ba7-8cf8-45dd-80f2-a8700e7dad2e" &&
                             l.FromDate == "2018-04-30")
                  .Select(d => ("2018-04-31" - "2018-04-30").TotalDays)
                  .Sum();
```

I hardcoded the dates for easy understanding (replace them in code).
Also, you need the replace them with your actual parameters: person.Id, userInputDate..

Comment: It gives exception ,System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: @AKoul, it does not give any exception because of it is a pseudo code, and I don't where you use ToDateTime, please provide your code.

Comment: My code       var diffMonthLeavesCount = db.LeaveRequest.Where(l => l.leaveTypeId == '1' && l.requestUserId == "5dc64ba7-8cf8-45dd-80f2-a8700e7dad2e" && l.FromDate == (Convert.ToDateTime("2018-04-30"))).Select(d => (last- d.FromDate).TotalDays).Sum();

Comment: l.FromDate is of type DateTime LeaveRequestModel.FromDate {get;set}         . So i am using Convert .Also note that i am selecting from db.LeaveRequest instead of leaveApprovedList

Answer (score -1):

It seems the comparison's are different as stated in the comment by tchelidze

In your sql you have 3 comparisons.

```
leaveTypeId = '1'  
requestUserId = '5dc64ba7-8cf8-45dd-80f2-a8700e7dad2e' 
FromDate = '2018-04-30'
```

In your linq you have 4 comparisons.

```
x.leaveTypeId == leaveTypeId //Assuming leaveTypeId ==1

x.requestUserId == person.Id  //Assuming person.Id == '5dc64ba7-8cf8-45dd-80f2-a8700e7dad2e' 

x.FromDate.Month == userInputDate.Month  //This compares month (int) instead of the date (DateTime) from sql

x.ToDate.Month == nextmonth.Month  //This does not exists in the sql compares month (int) as well
```

Comment: var diffMonthLeavesCount = db.LeaveRequest.Where(x => x.leaveTypeId == '1' && x.requestUserId == "5dc64ba7-8cf8-45dd-80f2-a8700e7dad2e" && x.FromDate == (Convert.ToDateTime(2018-04-30))).Select(x => SqlMethods.DateDiffDay("2018-30-04", "2018-30-04")).Sum();        This is my latest attempt. What should i pass to DateDiffDay as argument. The value of FromDate and Last is given in above comment.Please refer. And many many thanks for helping me :)  P.S- I am new to LINQ, and hate it so much, SQL queries are easier to write and debug.

Comment: From the MSDN DateDiffDay(DateTime, DateTime). So can you put DateDiffDay(new DateTime (blah blah blah),new DATETIME(blah blah blah)) instead? P.S.  the following are the creation method        new DateTime (DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, hours, minute, second);